# Fibre Channel LUN rescan and QLogic

Tags: linux, storage, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, qlogic

I have a serious problem with a SAN storage array connected to a Linux box through Fibre Channel. Here is the configuration :

- Debian with plain vanilla linux 2.6.27.25
- Fibre controller QLogic 4Gb dual port ( ISP2432 based)

Basically the problem is: how to get this #?@!! FC controller/driver to recognize properly configuration changes (new or removed LUNs) of the storage array?

1. when I create a new LUN on my array (typically a snapshot of some existing LUN) and map it to my HBA, I can't get it recognized properly : `rescan-scsi-bus -l -w -r` actually detects something ( a generic /dev/sgXX device) however no block device is created ( /dev/sdXX).
2. same thing when issuing a LIP and rescan manually:

   echo 1 > /sys/class/fc_host/host6/issue_lip

   echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host6/scan
3. if I remove an existing LUN, neither issuing LIPs and rescans or rescan-scsi-bus have any effect. The previous devices remain there and of course don't work ( "file -s /dev/sdXX -> I/O error").
4. reloading the qla2xxx driver works. However it's completely unworkable in a production environment.

Apparently this is [a very common problem with QLogic](http://solutions.qlogic.com/KanisaSupportSite/search.do?cmd=viewThread&docType=tkc&kcId=Post-2224043&sliceId=Post-2942005&dialogID=125420261&stateId=1%200%20125398091). Some sort of solution exists that works only when using the QLogic issued driver available only for RedHat and Suse enterprise distros : see [this explanation](http://solutions.qlogic.com/KanisaSupportSite/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=9223615&sliceId=SAL_Public&dialogID=4725381&stateId=0%200%204711370).

Additional info :

Here is the scsi devices before LIP and rescan:

```
# sg_map -x
/dev/sg0  0 0 0 0  0  /dev/sda
/dev/sg1  0 0 1 0  5  /dev/scd0
/dev/sg2  1 0 0 0  0  /dev/sdb
/dev/sg3  6 0 0 0  0  /dev/sdc
/dev/sg4  6 0 0 1  0  /dev/sdd
/dev/sg5  6 0 0 2  3
```

After a LIP and rescan, I have a new sg device, but no matching drive. If I reload the driver, a drive appear:

```
# sg_map -x
/dev/sg0  0 0 0 0  0  /dev/sda
/dev/sg1  0 0 1 0  5  /dev/scd0
/dev/sg2  1 0 0 0  0  /dev/sdb
/dev/sg3  6 0 0 0  0  /dev/sdc
/dev/sg4  6 0 0 1  0  /dev/sdd
/dev/sg5  6 0 0 2  3
/dev/sg6  6 0 0 3  3

~# sg_map -x
/dev/sg0  0 0 0 0  0  /dev/sda
/dev/sg1  0 0 1 0  5  /dev/scd0
/dev/sg2  1 0 0 0  0  /dev/sdb
/dev/sg3  8 0 0 0  0  /dev/sdc
/dev/sg4  8 0 0 1  0  /dev/sdd
/dev/sg5  8 0 0 2  0  /dev/sde
/dev/sg6  8 0 0 3  3
```

**Edit:** OK, obviously this is a tough nut to crack. I'll ask the LKML and report here.

Comment: That QLogic issued driver you're talking about can be compiled for other distros too -- it isn't a binary blob.

Comment: Fine, where can I find it then? I compiled the whole kernel, one more driver isn't a problem at all.

Comment: I'm having this problem, did you manage to find out anything?

Comment: Sorry, no info yet.

Comment: Here we are 10 years later and Qlogic still has a problem with detecting new luns. I'm seeing exactly this on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

In the off chance that the block device is being detected, but no /dev/ device is being created, you can manually create the device. This isn't optimal, but might limp you along. The  major and minor numbers are presented in /proc/partitions, and you can create your own block devices through the mknod command.

```
 # mknod /dev/sdg4 104 17
```

However, I feel your pain. QLogic offers driver download for RHEL and SUSE but it seems no other distros. OpenSUSE just might have the QLogic-branded drivers but I can't be certain of it. I'll check closer when I get to work.

**Edit**: I'm at work, and it does seem that the QLogic drivers on my SLES boxes are all the QLogic supplied one. Their OS support grid:

http://filedownloads.qlogic.com/files/Driver/71098/readme_driver_80223.html#os_support

And yet, when I download the bog-standard 2.6.27.25 kernel and look in the ./drivers/scsi/qla2xxx/qla_version.h file it is nearly the same version numbers as I have on my Novell distros (both SLES, and the free openSUSE). Which suggests that the solution you found for SLES/RHEL may actually work with a standard 2.6.27.25 kernel.

Comment: Unfortunately it can't work, because it mention using a file that is non existent ( /proc/scsi/qla2xxx/...) and a command (scsi-qlascan) that doesn't appear in the driver source code.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Wazoox I was faceing same pro with my SAN box i have google and some tips which follow if can try i think it will start working 
1   there is one tools call emcgrab tools u can run this tool to find out the driver of your qlogic driver is working or not.

which san box r u using?

there are some tips as follow..
http://forums.novell.com/novell-product-support-forums/suse-linux-enterprise-server-sles/sles-configure-administer/362473-lun-not-visible.html

http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/bizsupport/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1250262043169+28353475&threadId=1154098

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/connect-debian-etch-to-ibm-san-meaning-of-sns-scan-failed-570598/

http://solutions.qlogic.com/KanisaSupportSite/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=9223615&sliceId=SAL_Public&dialogID=4725381&stateId=0%200%204711370

Comment: Yes, lots of tips on google but most if not all of them are about RedHat/SuSe and the Qlogic proprietary driver... However one of your links gave me an idea, I'll be back :)

Comment: Well, uh, I tried with the latest firmware, but no luck...

Comment: From the four links, links 1, 2 and 4 are broken.